# How can I access members in an array of structures that I passed into a function by value?

Tags: c, arrays, function, structure, pass-by-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "InventoryManager.h"

void displayInventory(const struct Item items[], const int size)
{
printf("\n\n");
printf("Inventory\n");
printf("=========================================\n");
printf("Sku         Price       Quanity\n");
int index = 0;
for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    printf("%-10.0d  %-10.2f  %-10d\n", items[index].sku, items[index].price, items[index].quantity);
}
printf("=========================================\n");
}
```

I am getting red underlining under "items" when I try to access structure values within the array.

I have 3 files, inventoryManger.h, inventoryManager.c, shopping_lab_2.c ... The struct called Item was created in shopping_lab_2.c, and the function you are seeing on stack overflow is made in inventoryManager.c.

Comment: Looks like the definition of `struct Item` is not present. Is it in this file or a file this file is including?

Comment: I have 3 files, inventoryManger.h, inventoryManager.c, shopping_lab_2.c ... The struct called Item was created in shopping_lab_2.c, and the function you are seeing on stack overflow is made in inventoryManager.c.

Comment: You need to have the structure definition available in any file where it's used. If it's used in multiple .c files, you should put the definition in a .h file and have the .c files include it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how do you call your function. The program below works without errors or warnings:

```
struct Item{
 int sku;
 float price;
 int quantity; 
};  

void displayInventory(const struct Item items[], const int size)
{
printf("\n\n");
printf("Inventory\n");
printf("=========================================\n");
printf("Sku         Price       Quanity\n");
int index = 0;
for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
   printf("%-10.0d  %-10.2f  %-10d\n", items[index].sku, items[index].price,    items[index].quantity);
}
printf("=========================================\n");
}

int main()
{
 Item items[2] = {1, 1.1, 10, 2, 2.2, 20 }; // initialization
 displayInventory(items, 2);
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Inventory
=========================================
Sku         Price       Quanity
1           1.10        10        
2           2.20        20        
=========================================
```